# How to prompt a user for multiple entries in a list?

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm working on a vim plugin. There are a set of valid options for a configuration parameter. I would like the user to be able to select the options they want from a list.

This is similar to `inputlist`, but `inputlist` only returns the index of the single chosen element. I'd prefer it return the indexes of all chosen elements.

How would I create a mutliselect in vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly which kind of interface you have in mind, but since you mentioned `inputlist()`, I thought you could simply write a loop whose body would invoke it.

Maybe something like this:

```
let options_chosen = []
let options_valid  = [
                     \ 'foo',
                     \ 'bar',
                     \ 'baz',
                     \ 'qux',
                     \ 'norf'
                     \ ]

for i in range(1,len(options_valid))
    let choice = inputlist([ 'Select your options:' ]
                          \ + map(copy(options_valid), '(v:key+1).". ".v:val'))

    if choice >= 1 && choice <= len(copy(options_valid))
        let options_chosen += [copy(options_valid)[choice - 1]]
        let options_valid = filter(options_valid, 'v:val !=# options_chosen[-1]')
    else
        break
    endif

    redraw
endfor
```

If you execute this code, it should let you choose an option from the list `options_valid`. After each iteration, it should add the chosen item inside the list `options_chosen` and remove it from the list `options_valid`. The loop iterates as many times as there are items in `options_valid` initially. When you're done, you can stop the loop by hitting `Escape`.

It may not be what you want, because I don't know what interface you want to present to the user: a command, a mapping, an interactive buffer... But it may be a start, upon which you could build something else.

---

With an interactive buffer as the interface, I came up with this:

```
let s:options_valid = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'norf']

com! MultipleOptions call s:multiple_options()

fu! s:multiple_options() abort
    vnew | exe 'vert resize '.(&columns/3)
    setl bh=wipe bt=nofile nobl noswf nowrap
    if !bufexists('Multiple Options') | sil file Multiple\ Options | endif

    sil! 0put =s:options_valid
    sil! $d_
    setl noma ro

    nno <silent> <buffer> <nowait> q     :<c-u>close<cr>
    nno <silent> <buffer> <nowait> <cr>  :<c-u>call <sid>toggle_option()<cr>

    augroup multi_op_close
        au!
        au WinLeave <buffer> call s:close()
    augroup END
endfu

fu! s:close() abort
    let g:selected_options = exists('w:options_chosen')
                           \   ? map(w:options_chosen.lines, 's:options_valid[v:val-1]')
                           \   : []
    au! multi_op_close | aug! multi_op_close
    close
endfu

fu! s:toggle_option() abort
    if !exists('w:options_chosen')
        let w:options_chosen = { 'lines' : [], 'pattern' : '', 'id' : 0 }
    else
        if w:options_chosen.id
            call matchdelete(w:options_chosen.id)
            let w:options_chosen.pattern .= '|'
        endif
    endif

    if !empty(w:options_chosen.lines) && count(w:options_chosen.lines, line('.'))
        call filter(w:options_chosen.lines, "v:val != line('.')")
    else
        let w:options_chosen.lines += [ line('.') ]
    endif

    let w:options_chosen.pattern = '\v'.join(map(
                                 \               copy(w:options_chosen.lines),
                                 \               "'%'.v:val.'l'"
                                 \              ), '|')

    let w:options_chosen.id = !empty(w:options_chosen.lines)
                            \   ? matchadd('IncSearch', w:options_chosen.pattern)
                            \   : 0
endfu
```

If you execute the command `:MultipleOptions`, it should open a temporary vertical viewport, in which the options stored inside the list `s:options_valid` should be displayed.

From there, you can hit `Enter` to select or deselect the current line. When an option is selected, its line is colored with the highlighting group `IncSearch`.

When you're done, you can close the window hitting `q`, and all your chosen options should be inside `g:selected_options`.

Comment: the second one is amazing! that is precisely what I wanted, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

In [lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib) I provide a `lh#ui#check()` function that does exactly that. Its behaviour is similar to `confirm()` in text mode. i.e. I rely on an old trick that hacks the statusline. (This needs to play with `"\r"`, `:redraw` and so on)

You can see it live in the [screencast I've made for lh-tags](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-tags/blob/master/doc/screencast-LHTags.gif). Wait for the "Which kinds to you wish to display?" question. (In the screencast you should see the old code with `CHECK`, `CONFIRM` and `CHOOSE`)

BTW, the dialog used in lh-tags to choose one entry here can also be used (with the `tagged` parameter set to one) to select several entries at once.